# How can I add person to Rollbar globally in .NET Core 2.1 from IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rollbar

I do not know how add person to RollBar globally from IdentityUser.

This is my all Rollbar configuration in Startup.cs. I need help. Thanks for any help.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ConfigureRollbarSingleton();

    services.AddRollbarLogger(loggerOptions =>
         {
             loggerOptions.Filter = (loggerName, loglevel) => loglevel >= 
             LogLevel.Error;
         });

  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}

private void ConfigureRollbarSingleton() {
    Person person = new Person() {
    // how access to current user id, email and name? 
    Email = "...",
    Id = "...",
    UserName = "..."
};

RollbarLocator.RollbarInstance
// minimally required Rollbar configuration:
.Configure(new RollbarConfig(rollbarAccessToken) {
     Environment = rollbarEnvironment
})
.Config.Person = person;;
}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
  app.UseRollbarMiddleware();
   }
```

Comment: Inject a singleton, which provides an accessor to get user information. and use that to configure your person

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you add example of code? I can't imagine it. Thanks

Comment: I would but I need a better example of how you normally configure Rollbar, but you should be able do something like this,  pass the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your singleton and then resolve the httpcontext from the accessor, then you can obtain the user details from the UserManager `UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)`

Comment: I have updated post.

Comment: this still doesn't make sense, what does `ConfigureRollbarSingleton()` do I see you setting properties on a person but how does that configure rollbar?  Where are you registering the service?

Comment: The purpose of the Startup class is configuring both the application Dependency Injection container and request pipeline. It is not bound to a request and only executed when the application starts, hence the name Startup.

A typical place where you would use the logged in user is [middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) and [controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: @XueliChen You also register factories in the Startup, and factories can have request information